# SHA-256 Hash and base64 encoding

Tags: sql, postgresql

With the string `"123456Adrian Wapcaplet"` I need to

1. generate the SHA-256 hash
2. take the least significant 128 bits of the hash
3. represent these bits in base64 encoding

I need help with #1 and #3. Below is how I generate this in Linux

```
$ echo -n "123456Adrian Wapcaplet" | shasum -a 256 | cut -c33-64 | xxd -r -p | base64

jNWe9TyaqmgxG3N2fgl15w==
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the pgcrypto extension:

```
create extension pgcrypto;
```

Then you can use the `digest` function to do sha256. The rest of the functions you'll need are built in:

```
select encode(substring(digest('123456Adrian Wapcaplet', 'sha256') from 17), 'base64');
```

Note that there's an implicit cast from `text` to `bytea` performed here when calling `digest`. It will use the default encoding for the database. To avoid problems due to environmental differences you can specify the encoding for the conversion:

```
digest(convert_to('123456Adrian Wapcaplet', 'utf8'), 'sha256')
```